# Tab Navigator wrapped in SwitchNavigator unable to get title bar with back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Right now I have a switch navigator with all my screens to be able to route everything. The set up is as follows. My App starts up takes me to the login page once logged in takes me to the TabNavigator which has my home screen. My home screen has a list of events. When clicked on the event it takes you to a more detailed page. This detailed page should have a title bar with a back button to go back to the main home screen. As of now there is no way to set the title bar to go back.

```
render() {

         return(<AppContainer />);

  }
}

const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home {
    screen: Home
  },
  Settings
});



const AppStackNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Login,  
  },
  Signup: { 
    screen: Signup,
    navigationOptions: {
      //title: 'Registration',
      //header: null
    }
  },
  Main: {
    screen: HomeTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {

    }
  },
  Event: {
    screen: Event,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Pickup",
    }
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

The "Event" screen is the screen from the list, this should have the title "Pickup" with a back button but its not shown

A gif of the navigation:
http://recordit.co/bmAWxsIEpp

Comment: Back button in the header is from stackNavigator. You can wrap your bottomTab with stack navigator and you will have the back button.

Comment: but in your situation, you can create a dummy component, so it is part of stack navigation. When you click on the list item, you `push` the clicked items info to the dummy component.

Comment: Changing it from switchStackNavigator to createStackNavigator worked, and now my back button and the title bar is there!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ziyo for pointing me in the right direction.

switchStackNavigator and stacknavigator are used for different things. They are not interchangeable. switchStack actually is created so there is no back button for situations like authentication where you want to only show a single screen.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

Comment: You didn't need to change you switchNavigation. As I mentioned, wrapping tabNavigation into stack would work. I will post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home {
    screen: Home
  },
  Settings
});

const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  Main: HomeTabNavigator
})

const AppStackNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  ...
  Main: {
    screen: StackNavigation, // Right here you would have a stack navigation
    navigationOptions: {

    }
  },
  ...
});
```